# Pandas regex comprehension - isolate single result

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that's been extracted from an SQL server, and I used regex to extract a string of three dimensions. I need all three dimensions in three new columns so I have used a regular expression for a number optionally separated by a period, and created a column from this findall result. But the result shows as a list and I am unable to index the second dimension. Due to the urgency I have been able to temporarily solve this with a lookaround. But how can I directly extract

dimension column extract - not all are in this format

```
[1103.5 x 308.8 x 25.4 mm]
[33.3 x 13 x 9.5mm]
[136.5 x 15 x 12.7 mm]
```

code extract for finding dims

```
dims = re.compile(r'.*mm', flags=re.I)
x_dim = re.compile(r'^([0-9]*\.?[0-9]?)', flags=re.I)
y_dim = re.compile(r'(\d+\.?\d?)', flags=re.I)
# y_dim = re.compile(r'(?<=x\s)(\d+\.?\d?)(?=\sx)', flags=re.I) # lookaround solution
df['Dimensions'] = df['Part_Extended_Desc'].str.findall(dims)
df['x'] = df['Part_Extended_Desc'].str.findall(x_dim)
df['y'] = df['Part_Extended_Desc'].str.findall(y_dim)
df['trial'] = df['y'][0][1] # does not work
df['second_dim'] = df.dim_list.apply(lambda x:x[1]) # also doesn't work (list index out of range)
print(df.tail(50))
```

sample output using the findall result

```
[1493.4, 204.2, 25.4, 0013, 900, 4]
[136.5, 15, 12.7, 001, 900, 2]
```

I would need a column for 1493.4 and a second column for 204.2 - I can do the first one but how would I create a column for specific indexes in the regex results. I have tried lambda, list comprehension, and everything else I can think of.

So far I cannot find a similar question online and I know it should be simple - but its taken me 2 days!

Many thanks for all your help

EDIT:

To confirm, the initial regex results are not always in the same format, sometimes as zz.zmm x zz.zmm x zmm, sometimes as zz x zz mm, there are many cases where it is preferable to extract a list of the numbers only, not with a strong, specific regex pattern.

Additionally, my focus is on obtaining only list item n to a new column and not every item in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are looking for way of expanding column holding lists, assuming that number of matches is equal in all record, you might do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'dim':['10x10','12x10','10x12']})
df['dim_list'] = df.dim.str.findall(r'\d+')
df[['width','height']] = df.dim_list.apply(pd.Series)
print(df)
```

output:

```
     dim  dim_list width height
0  10x10  [10, 10]    10     10
1  12x10  [12, 10]    12     10
2  10x12  [10, 12]    10     12
```

If only n-th element is required you might use `lambda` following way:

```
df['second_dim'] = df.dim_list.apply(lambda x:x[1])
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful - what about when each list has n number of objects but you only need, say the 5th?

Comment: Thank you, this is how I was trying it myself but the output message is "IndexError: string index out of range"

Comment: or "list index out of range" - depending on whether i try to reference the original string or the regex list derived from it

Comment: @damien1991 this mean you have record with less elements in list than you expect

Comment: Yes, as mentioned the raw strings that these are extracted from vary a lot, which is why I need to isolate the numbers as floats, and then if there are more than 2 floats, isolate the second. Perhaps this would work in a conditional try/except loop?

Comment: @damien1991 then you might use ternary with checking length of list for example `lambda x:x[1] if len(x)>=2 else -1` will take 2nd element if list length is at least 2 otherwise it will provide `-1`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the format as shown in the answer you can use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dimensions':['1103.5 x 308.8 x 25.4 mm','33.3 x 13 x 9.5mm','136.5 x 15 x 12.7 mm']})
>>> df[['Height','Width','Length']] = df['Dimensions'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*x\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*x\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*mm\b')
>>> df
                   Dimensions  Height  Width Length
0    1103.5 x 308.8 x 25.4 mm  1103.5  308.8   25.4
1           33.3 x 13 x 9.5mm    33.3     13    9.5
2        136.5 x 15 x 12.7 mm   136.5     15   12.7
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iAzuAa/1)

*Details*:

- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: a number
- `\s*x\s*` - an `x` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 2: a number
- `\s*x\s*` - an `x` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 3: a number
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `mm\b` - an `mm` as a whole word.